# split txt file to multiple files named according to their contents in Python

Tags: python, split

I have a large .txt file in JSON format which leads on as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "arbitrary name 1",
    "Detail 1": "text here",
    "Detail 2": "text here",
    "Detail 3": "text here",
},
{
    "Name": "arbitrary name 1",
    "Detail 1": "text here",
    "Detail 2": "text here",
    "Detail 3": "text here",
},
```

and so on, for 2000 entries.

What I am trying to do is split this file into individual .txt files, while retaining the JSON formatting.

So, in essence, I need to split the file after the }, to make 2000 new .txt files as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "arbitrary name 1",
    "Detail 1": "text here",
    "Detail 2": "text here",
    "Detail 3": "text here",
}
```

Furthermore, these 2000 new .txt files must be named according to the "Name" attribute, so this example file would be named "arbitrary name 1.txt".

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I am able to split the file using bash, but this doesn't allow for the naming that I need.

I am hoping someone can help me find a Python solution that can also name the files correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is trivial if you can parse the whole file; then it's just a loop over the parts of the outer JSON list. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
for line in data:
    with open(line['Name'] + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(line))
```

Be aware that the result json is not sorted afterwards but it should be properly splitted.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great. The ordering of the resulting json files is an issue unfortunately. Are you aware of any way of maintaining the order as in the original file? Thanks again.