# Split JSON File into multiple JSONs according to their ID?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a JSON File which looks like this:

```
{"one":"Some data", "two":"Some data",...}
```

and so on...

I want to split all the ID's into separate files according to the name of the ID, For example:

```
one.json
{"one":"Some data"}
two.json
{"two":"Some data"}
```

and so on.

I got a reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858879/split-txt-file-to-multiple-files-named-according-to-their-contents-in-python). But my problem is slightly different. What can I modify to achieve the separate text files?

Comment: What's the point of having the variable name the same as the key name? You're just messing with the namespace by added loads of unnecessary names

Comment: Please don't tag with python-2.7 *and* python-3.x unless you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I won't teach you how to do file I/O and assume you can do that yourself.

Once you have loaded the original file as a `dict` with the `json` module, do

```
>>> org = {"one":"Some data", "two":"Some data"}
>>> dicts = [{k:v} for k,v in org.items()]
>>> dicts
[{'two': 'Some data'}, {'one': 'Some data'}]
```

which will give you a list of dictionaries that you can dump to a file (or separate files named after the keys), if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

After loading the JSON file you can treat it as a dictionary in python and then save the contents in file by looping through as you would in normal python dictionary.
Here is an example related to what you want to achieve

```
Data = {"one":"Some data", "two":"Some data"}
for item in Data:
    name = item + '.json'
    file = open(name, 'w')
    file.write('{"%s":"%s"}' % (item, Data[item]))
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

after getting the json data into a variable,do

```
a = {"one":"Some data", "two":"Some data"}
for k,v in a.items():
    with open(k+".json","w") as f:
        f.write('{"%s" : "%s"}' %(k,v))
```

and output is :

```
one.json => {"one":"Some data"}
```

and

```
two.json => {"two":"Some data"}
```